# Depth and kernel of multiplication map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebras, dimension-theory-algebra

If $A$ is a commutative $k$-algebra, $\mu: A\otimes_k A\rightarrow A$ is its multplication map and $I$ is the kernel of that map (viewed as an $A\otimes_k A$-module map) then what is the relationship between:

Depth(A) and the number of generators of $I$?

Comment: Exactlly sorry I wrote too quickly

Comment: What is Depth(A)?

Comment: The length of the longest possible regular sequence in $A$.

Comment: The number of generators is at least $\dim A$ which is bigger or equal to the depth. To see this (the first inequality), you can use the isomorphism $I/I^2\simeq \Omega_{A/k}$ (the module of Kahler differential forms).

Comment: @Cantlog Which depth? A commutative $k$-algebra hasn't only one maximal ideal to talk about its depth.

Comment: Dear @user26857: one can consider the maximum of the depths of the localizations at maximal ideals, or the length of a maximal regular sequence of non-invertible elements. These two quantities are certainly different in general, but there is an obvious inequality and both are bounded by $\dim A$.

Comment: @Cantlog How could we show that the minimal number of generators of $\Omega_{A/k}$ is $\ge\dim A$?

Comment: @user26857: essentially because $\Omega_{A/k}$ is dual to the tangent spaces.